# threejs webgl shader cant compile

Tags: javascript, three.js

i am new to webgl and i am currently learning shaders. i am currently trying to wrap a texture around a sphere to give an earth globe image but faced issues when trying to do so, with the fragments and vertex glsl.

this is the error i am currently facing, and it occurs when i try to load the texture

```
three.module.js:17071 THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error:  0 35715 false gl.getProgramInfoLog Vertex shader is not compiled.
```

the following code is for main.js

```
import './style.css'
import * as THREE from 'three'
import * as dat from 'dat.gui'
import vertexShader from './vertex.glsl'
import fragmentShader from './fragment.glsl'

// Debug
const gui = new dat.GUI()

// Canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas.webgl')

// Scene
const scene = new THREE.Scene()

// Objects
const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5,50,50);

// Materials
const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader()


const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    vertexShader,
    fragmentShader,
    uniforms: {
        globeTexture: {
            value: loader.load('globe.jpg')
        }
    }
})

// material.color = new THREE.Color(0xff0000)
// const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );

// Mesh
const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material)
scene.add(sphere)

// Lights

const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.1)
pointLight.position.x = 2
pointLight.position.y = 3
pointLight.position.z = 4
scene.add(pointLight)

/**
 * Sizes
 */
const sizes = {
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight
}

window.addEventListener('resize', () =>
{
    // Update sizes
    sizes.width = window.innerWidth
    sizes.height = window.innerHeight

    // Update camera
    camera.aspect = sizes.width / sizes.height
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix()

    // Update renderer
    renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height)
    renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))
})

/**
 * Camera
 */
// Base camera
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, sizes.width / sizes.height, 0.1, 100)
camera.position.x = 0
camera.position.y = 0
camera.position.z = 20
scene.add(camera)

// Controls
// const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, canvas)
// controls.enableDamping = true

/**
 * Renderer
 */
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: canvas,
    antialias: true
})
renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height)
renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))

/**
 * Animate
 */

const clock = new THREE.Clock()

const tick = () =>
{

    const elapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime()

    // Update objects
    sphere.rotation.y = .5 * elapsedTime

    // Update Orbital Controls
    // controls.update()

    // Render
    renderer.render(scene, camera)

    // Call tick again on the next frame
    window.requestAnimationFrame(tick)
}

tick()
```

code for fragment.glsl
uniform sampler2D globeTexture;

```
varying vec2 vertexUV; 

void main() {

    gl_FragColor = texture2D(globeTexture, vertexUV);
 ;
}
```

vertex.glsl

```
varying vec2 vertexUV;

void main(){
    
vertexUv = uv;

gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );

}
```

thanks guys in advance.

Comment: In `vertex.glsl` where is `uv` defined?

Comment: `uv` is definied by three.js probably and `ShaderMaterial`

Comment: However `globeTexture` is not defiined anywhere

Comment: its defined at fragcolour

Comment: @pailhead its defined at fragcolour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fixed code:

```js
// Canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas.webgl')

// Scene
const scene = new THREE.Scene()

// Objects
const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5, 50, 50);

// Materials
const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();


const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexShader').textContent,
  fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentShader').textContent,
  uniforms: {
    globeTexture: {
      value: loader.load('https://threejs.org/examples/textures/uv_grid_opengl.jpg')
    }
  }
})

// Mesh
const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
scene.add(sphere)

// Lights

const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.1)
pointLight.position.x = 2
pointLight.position.y = 3
pointLight.position.z = 4
scene.add(pointLight)

/**
 * Sizes
 */
const sizes = {
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight
}

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  // Update sizes
  sizes.width = window.innerWidth
  sizes.height = window.innerHeight

  // Update camera
  camera.aspect = sizes.width / sizes.height
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix()

  // Update renderer
  renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height)
  renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))
})

/**
 * Camera
 */
// Base camera
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, sizes.width / sizes.height, 0.1, 100)
camera.position.x = 0
camera.position.y = 0
camera.position.z = 20
scene.add(camera)

/**
 * Renderer
 */
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas: canvas,
  antialias: true
})
renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height)
renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))

/**
 * Animate
 */

const clock = new THREE.Clock()

const tick = () => {

  const elapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime()

  // Update objects
  sphere.rotation.y = .5 * elapsedTime

  // Render
  renderer.render(scene, camera)

  // Call tick again on the next frame
  window.requestAnimationFrame(tick)
}

tick()
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.134.0/build/three.js"></script>
<canvas class="webgl"></canvas>

<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
varying vec2 vertexUV;

void main(){
    
    vertexUV = uv;

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );

}
 
</script>

<script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
uniform sampler2D globeTexture;

varying vec2 vertexUV; 

void main() {

    gl_FragColor = texture2D(globeTexture, vertexUV);

}
 
</script>
```

- You did not define the uniform `globeTexture`.
- There is a typo in the vertex shader. It should be `vertexUV` instead of `vertexUv`.

Comment: yo thanks bro, it works, missed type vertexUV